# Disable shift-delete for file deletion

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, shortcut-keys, files, delete

As an re-education procedure in order to reduce (likely) future data loss, I wish to disable the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> functionality to delete files in Ubuntu (11.10 and 12.04). Also, if I could replace it with a "Stop that!" popup alert, even better.

I know there are data recovery tools for such cases, but better never put my important data at risk due to such mistakes. And I found nothing similar around, so I hope someone here can show me how, if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you define a shortcut on window manager's level, it won't go to Nautilus. Combined with [Zenity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenity), you can even show yourself an alert.

First make sure Zenity is installed

```
sudo apt-get install zenity
```

Now go to System Settings (or run `gnome-control-center`) → *Keyboard* → *Shortcuts* tab, select *Custom shortcuts* (last item in the left menu), click <kbd>+</kbd> to create new shortcut. Call it however you want, and set this command:

```
zenity --error --text='Stop doing that!'
```

Once you add the shortcut, assign Shift+Delete to it. Now every time you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>, you get a warning box. Unfortunately this means you can't use this shortcut within any application, but it's rather quick workaround to get rid of a habit.

Comment: It worked wonderfully. Better this way, as I can't work around it, I'll just learn to use regular Delete. Many thanks, jnv!

Comment: Now I understand what you meant by 'within any application'. The alert sometimes pop up on text editors while shift-selecting text and deleting it in rapid succession. A small quirk, but this is not a real shortcut on any application so far, so no big deal.

Comment: I clicked on + and created `custom shortcut`, but I am not able to assigh `Shift+Delete` to it. BTW, I am using 12.04.

Comment: @PraveenSripati Once the shortcut is created, double click `Disabled` in the right column, it will change to `New shortcut…`, then press `Shift+Del`. If you can't assign this one particular shortcut, it's possible the shortcut is already handled by Compiz. Or maybe it's not assignable in Precise; I am still on Oneiric so I can't test this.

Comment: @Praveen Sripati I could assign it without any hassle on Precise and Natty.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this tip, jnv. From now on, I won't accidentally delete my files for good anymore. :)

Comment: If you don't want to install zenity just for this, you can use the Ubuntu's default notification system by setting the command to something like: `notify-send 'Error' 'Shift+Delete not allowed for safety.`

Answer (score 1):

You can generally prevent the files from being deleted either by Shift + Del or the normal deletion by adjusting the permission of the directories to read-only for users. Set it in a way that administrators can only modify any content.

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution in Ubuntu 20.04 is to go to Settings → *Devices* → *Keyboard* and adding a new shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> with no command in it.

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04 the path is Setiings  →  *Keyboard Shortcuts*, not Settings → *Devices* → *Keyboard*. Also, you cannot add a shortcut without a command, but you can add gibberish as a command (like "blablabla") and your suggestion would work. You may [edit] your answer to improve it based on this comment, if you wish. If you do that please ping me in a comment (using @BeastOfCaerbannog) and I will gladly upvote it, since it's a nice suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

To build off the [answer from sorrow-poetry](https://askubuntu.com/a/1295685):

You can set the command to `:` to ensure that <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd> does nothing.